# How to plot based on values of 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df = 

     id_easy  latitude  longitude  cluster
0         a1   45.1076     7.4920        0
0         b1   45.1064     7.5013        0
1         c1   44.9498     7.5010        1
1         d1   44.9656     7.5084        1
2         e1   45.0846     7.5277        2
2         f1   45.1650     7.7950        2
```

I want to visualize:

- longitude and latitude values of `id_easy` `a1` `b1` of `cluster` `0` in different colors and the rest of the data gray
- longitude and latitude values of `id_easy` `c1` `d1` of `cluster` `1` in different colors and the rest of the data gray
- longitude and latitude values of `id_easy` `e1` `f1` of `cluster` `2` in different colors and the rest of the data gray

I have this:

```
for index_in_red in df.index.unique():
    my_dpi=96
    plt.figure(figsize=(600/my_dpi, 400/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)

    plt.plot(df.loc[df.index != index_in_red,'longitude'],df.loc[df.index != index_in_red,'latitude'] ,
             color='silver', marker='o',linestyle='',linewidth=50, markersize=2)

    plt.plot(df.loc[index_in_red,'longitude'],df.loc[index_in_red,'latitude']  ,
              color='maroon',marker='o',linestyle='',linewidth=2, markersize=3)

    plt.show()
```

But it gives me all values of `id_easy` in maroon color, but I want them to be in different color

Desired output:

[image: For every values of id_easy I have different color]

For every values of id_easy I have different color

Comment: Do you want 3 plots for different clusters? Otherwise how would you see *the rest of the data gray*?

Comment: @QuangHoang I added desired output. 3 different plots, different color for every couple of id_easy in given cluster 0 (data of clusters 1 and 2 will be gray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with seaborn:

```
for cluster in df.cluster.unique():

    # mask the cluster of interest
    is_cluster = df.cluster.eq(cluster)

    # plot the other clusters in gray
    ax = df[~is_cluster].plot.scatter(x='latitude',y='longitude', c='gray')

    # plot the cluster of interest in different colors
    sns.scatterplot(data=df[is_cluster],
                    x='latitude', 
                    y='longitude',
                    hue='id_easy',
                    ax=ax)

    # you can do other stuff with ax here
    # ax.set_title(...)...

    plt.show()
```

At the end, you will have 3 plots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not perfectly clear to me, is this what you are looking for?

[image]

in case this is the code I used:

```
df2=df.set_index('cluster')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 12), nrows=3,ncols=1,constrained_layout=True)

for clus in df2.index.unique():
    axs[clus].plot(df2.latitude,df2.longitude,'o',color='grey',markersize=12)
    axs[clus].plot(df2.loc[clus].latitude.iloc[0],df2.loc[clus].longitude.iloc[0],'o',markersize=12)
    axs[clus].plot(df2.loc[clus].latitude.iloc[1],df2.loc[clus].longitude.iloc[1],'o',markersize=12)

    axs[clus].set_xlabel('Latitude')
    axs[clus].set_ylabel('Longitude')
    axs[clus].set_title('Cluster '+str(clus))
```

Comment: Instead of 2 blue dots, I want 2 different colored dots